# Using WHERE in XSL stylesheet?

Tags: xml, xslt

Here is our XML:

```
<Mediendaten>
  <Mediendaten mmid="24990">
    <type>Sommer</type>
    <url size="pic800x">...</url>
    <url size="ltoTeaserBoxImage">...</url>
  </Mediendaten>
  <Mediendaten mmid="202925">
    <type>Sommer</type>    
    <url size="pic800x">...</url>
    <url size="ltoTeaserBoxImage">...</url>
  <Mediendaten mmid="32589">
    <type>Winter</type>
    <url size="pic800x">...</url>
    <url size="ltoTeaserBoxImage">...</url>
  </Mediendaten>
  <Mediendaten mmid="66325214">
    <type>Winter</type>    
    <url size="pic800x">...</url>
    <url size="ltoTeaserBoxImage">...</url>
  </Mediendaten>
</Mediendaten>
```

And here our XSL:

```
<xsl:template match="/Mediendaten">
    <xsl:apply-templates select="Mediendaten[@mmid][1]/url">
    </xsl:apply-templates>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="Mediendaten/url[@size = 'ltoTeaserBoxImage']">
    <xsl:variable name="url_bilder">
        <xsl:value-of select="."></xsl:value-of>
    </xsl:variable>
</xsl:template>
```

How do we get our stylesheet to only select the FIRST Mediadaten where `type=winter` AND `@size=ltoTeaserBoxImage`?

Many thanks in advance for any help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The expression you are looking for is this....

```
<xsl:apply-templates select="Mediendaten[type='Winter'][url[@size = 'ltoTeaserBoxImage']][1]" />
```

This would also work

```
<xsl:apply-templates select="Mediendaten[type='Winter'][url/@size = 'ltoTeaserBoxImage'][1]" />
```